# while transfer onnx model to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype float64

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Add' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'

Comment: Please state your problem better: what's your task, what you're trying to do, expected behavior, actual behavior, code that you have written so far, tensorflow/python versions

Comment: Clearly, one Op in your model is defined as Float64 instead of Float32. This can happen if you used numpy ops instead of TensorFlow in your model for add operation. Please check your model and try to use TF ops wherever applicable. Or force the dtype of numpy ops to Float32.